# Is emulation mode in IE11 same as setting meta EmulateIE7 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, emulation

For IE11 browser I use I see this message on console :

“HTML1122: Internet Explorer is running in Enterprise Mode emulating IE8.”

Searching this error code on https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-IE&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.HTML1122) 
Displays : “This mode is configured by IT Management for specific sites. If an individual user needs to turn it off on a webpage, uncheck the Enterprise Mode option in the Tools menu. For more about management of Enterprise Mode, see the IT documentation.”

This is fine but I want to control this by setting the meta tag.

Will adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` to head have same affect as "running in Enterprise Mode emulating IE8" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Using `content="ie=8"` will get similar results but not the same.

Enterprise mode IE (EMIE) is a special mode designed to provide [greater compatibility with IE8](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687) than was possible using x-ua-compatible.  IE8 standards mode was introduced with IE9 and some organizations were able to use it to migrate their legacy apps.  Other organizations struggled, however.  Because there was reliance on the then-current behavior of IE8 standards mode, IE11 introduced EMIE to help those who still struggled.

Some of this complexity is what led to the clean break being introduced with MS Edge.

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot enable or disable EMIE through markup. (You can do it through group policy, however, and that may help if your concern is related to rolling it out to a number of machines.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance